# Unexpected token given when loading import() with Webpack 4.24.0 or higher

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've been on a dependencies upgrade mission and I have found when upgrading Webpack to 4.24.0 or above I get this failure:

```
ERROR in ./src/js/components/App.jsx 35:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (35:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import ReactModal from 'react-modal';
| var RoomListings = React.lazy(function () {
>   return import('./RoomListings.jsx');
| });
| var RoomDetails = React.lazy(function () {
 @ ./src/js/index.js 3:0-39 6:74-77
 @ multi ./src/js/index.js
```

It's failing on the import but what is frustrating is that nothing has changed in either my Webpack or Babel config which are below:

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/js/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: "js/[name].js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html-loader" },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
      { test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,  use: [{
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: { 
            limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
            name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
        } 
      }]}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
  "plugins": ["add-react-displayname", "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import", "emotion"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["dynamic-import-node"]
    }
  }
}
```

I am assuming something is either missing or misconfigured, but after hours of searching SO and Google, none of the existing answer appear to help.

Comment: I think it's because of `function() {...}`. That's not valid JavaScript syntax. Either name the functions or use `() => {...}` if you don't want to name them.

Comment: I believe that is Babel converting it to ```function()```. If you take a look at the original code, I am using ```() => {...}``` https://github.com/mwinteringham/restful-booker-platform/blob/master/ui/js/src/js/components/AdminContainer.jsx#L12 suggestions?

Comment: Can you extract the example into a small standalone repository I can build?